# 2 items segment control with UITableView iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm just wondering why that it's hard to maintain the scroll position on segment change. I tried to do it with saving the index paths of the table view and apply it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. But it's a workaround and is there a way to maintain the scroll position event the segment changed.

I'm using one table view and how about use of 2 tableviews? Is there a simple in-build method to do this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Use 2 table views and just give them tags or on the base of segment change.

Comment: Use 2 `UITableview`. On select segment index just show hide your UITableview. So you don't need to manage index. Just maintain a flag for that.

Comment: 2 tableviews work for me well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need the `UITableView` to animate between states when you change the `selectedSegmentIndex` of the `UISegmentedControl`?

If not, use two `UITableView`s.

If so, use `scrollToRow(at indexPath: IndexPath, at scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition, animated: Bool)` after you update your tableView contents from within your `UISegmentedControl`'s value-change handler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used 2 table view controllers and problem solved.